# Prove $C([0,1]),||.||)$ is not complete with $||x||= \text{sup}_{t \in [0,1]}|tx(t)|$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Prove $C([0,1]),||.||)$ is not complete where $||x||= \text{sup}_{t \in [0,1]}|tx(t)|$ is a norm.

**The solution given in my lectures:**

We take a Cauchy sequence defined as follows:
$$ f_n(t)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt t} && ,\frac{1}{n} \leq t \leq 1 \\ \sqrt n &&, 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n}  \end{cases}   $$

To prove it is Cauchy we take n>m

$$||f_n(t)-f_m(t)||=\text{sup}_{t \in [0,1]}|t(f_n(t)-f_m(t))|=\text{max}\{\text{sup}_{t \in [0,\frac{1}{n}]}|t(\sqrt n -\sqrt m)| ,\text{sup}_{t \in [\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{m}]}|t(\frac{1}{\sqrt t}-\sqrt m)|,0\} $$
Since in $[\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{m}], \frac{1}{\sqrt t}-\sqrt m \leq \sqrt n-\sqrt m$
$$||f_n(t)-f_m(t)||= \text{max}\{\frac{1}{n}(\sqrt n -\sqrt m) ,\frac{1}{m}(\sqrt n -\sqrt m) \} ....(\alpha)$$
$$||f_n(t)-f_m(t)||  \to 0 , \text{ when } n,m\to \infty....(\beta)$$

If $\exists f \in C([0,1]) \text{ such that } ||f_n-f|| \to 0$, then

$ \text{sup}_{t \in [0,1]}|t(f_n-f)|\to 0 $,

$\forall t_0 \in [0,1], |f_n(t_0)-f(t_0)| \to 0$,

$\forall t_0 \in (0,1] ,f(t_0)=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(t_0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt t_0} ....(\gamma)$

, but no continuous function in $[0,1]$ exists , that coincides with $\frac{1}{\sqrt t}$ in $(0,1] $

**Can someone clarify these points:**

-In $(\alpha)$ how is that they found that second sup? It doesn't seem right that $ \text{sup}_{t \in [\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{m}]}|t(\frac{1}{\sqrt t}-\sqrt m)||= \frac{1}{m}(\sqrt n -\sqrt m)$, that would be like requiring $t$ to be $1/m$ and $1/n$ at the same time

-In $(\beta)$ why are they taking a double limit when $m, n \to \infty$ is this legal?, I 've only seen that in Cauchy sequences proofs we have to find the expresion that is less that an $\varepsilon$ for some $n$ and $m$,whya aren't they doing that?

-In $(\gamma)$ they are just rewriting the previous line using $lim$, so why are they leaving out the $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

($\alpha$) It doesn't matter. All you need is an inequality, and $\frac{1}{m}(\sqrt n -\sqrt m)$ is an upper bound.

($\beta$) It's the same. Being Cauchy is $\lim_{m,n\to\infty}\|f_n-f_m\|=0$, which is the same as the common phrasing of "Cauchy" that you use.

($\gamma)$  Because it doesn't fit the expression $1/\sqrt{t_0}$, and it doesn't hurt the argument.

Comment: ok, so $(\alpha)$ is in fact an inequality, so that should have been a typo, right?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the equalence of the usual Cauchy seq definition and the one you wrote? Can that be proven?

Comment: Most likely. As for Cauchy, the definition you use is "given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that whenever $n,m>n_0$, we have $\|f_n-f_m\|<\varepsilon$. That's exactly how I would define $\lim_{m,n\to\infty}\|f_n-f_m\|=0$; do you have another definition in mind?

Comment: yes that's the one

Comment: it's just that the double limit is uncommon for me

Comment: Two-variable functions are allowed to have limits, too ;)

Comment: ok, I can see it as a 2-variable function. Is there any way to formalize $(\gamma)$?, when taking the limit for $n \to \infty$ I do it graphically since one of the subdomains of the function shrinks to zero.

Comment: Any continuous function on a compact set is bounded. As $1/\sqrt t$ is not bounded on $(0,1]$, it cannot possibly be bounded on $[0,1]$.  By the way, your original $f$ is not continuous; I think it's a typo and you need $\sqrt n$ instead of $n$.

Comment: yes that  was a typo, thanks, I fixed it. I put n, because I was thinking that all this argument could work with $1/n$ instead of $1/ \sqrt n$, couldn't it? So I don't know why they chose to make things slightly more complicated with that choice

Comment: And checking the Cauchy limit definition, it seems like they use limsup instead in your definition, how is that the same?

Comment: They need something that divides $t$ and still goes to zero, so $1/t$ wouldn't work. As for limsup, if the limsup of something non-negative is zero, then the limit exists. It's a matter of taste, I think.

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized I don't know how they found that limit in $(\alpha)$, first I have to get rid of the max right? and then in the remaining term how do I find the limit for $\sqrt n /m$ ? if I first do the limit for $m \to \infty$, n disappears, and then I have the limit of zero for $n \to \infty$, which is zero. Is that correct?

Comment: No, you cannot take one variable to infinity while not touching the other; that would not address all possible cases (you need to consider, for instance, the case $n=m$). I had not looked at the estimates. The second one inside the max is wrong, it's too big. It is not true that $(\sqrt n-\sqrt m)/m$ goes to zero if $n>m$ (try with $n=m^2$, for instance). But without making the crude estimate, one has to bound, for $\tfrac1n\leq t\leq\tfrac1m$, $$t\,\Big(\frac1{\sqrt t}-\sqrt m\Big)\leq \sqrt t+t\sqrt m\leq\frac1{\sqrt m}+\frac1{\sqrt m}.$$

Comment: Do you mean "the second one inside the max is wrong,  it's too big", Do you mean $\text{sup}_{t \in [\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{m}]}|t(\frac{1}{\sqrt t}-\sqrt m)  \leq \frac{1}{m}(\sqrt n -\sqrt m)|$ is wrong? Or do you mean with the "=", which is what  we identified as a typo in $ (\alpha)$? what 's too big? I've double checked and can't find anything wrong. Your last calculation seemed to be the missing part

Comment: It's not wrong, but the estimate is too big as it does not go to zero. If $n=m^2$. then $$\frac1m\,(\sqrt n-\sqrt m)=\frac{m-\sqrt m}m\to1.$$

Comment: I've been reflecting on the last part of the proof, that is after Cauchyness is proven. Is it really necessary to write all those following lines? Can't I just go on to  take the limit: and conclude: $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n=1/\sqrt n $ in $ (0,1]$ as we do in real analysis to find the limit of a sequence of functions and from that conclude that the Cauchy sequence converges to a non continuous function in [0,1]  and therefore there is no completeness?$

Comment: Yes and no. In a proof of non-completeness, you want to exhibit a Cauchy sequence that does not converge, which is what the proof does. An easier but less conceptually clear proof can be done using your approach. You could embed your space in the space of bounded functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$, and there show that your sequence converges to a non-continuous function (and you wouldn't need to do the Cauchy stuff, a convergent sequence is Cauchy). Computationally easier, conceptually muddier.

Comment: I think the reason of the complication in my approach is that the limit I am suggesting is a limit that should be done with the new norm instead of the "usual" one for which we have all the theorems, and so we don't really know how to calculate that limit. Hence we need to do it indirectly by putting $||f_n-f||$ to be able to use the definition of the new norm as they do.

Comment: So the limit I am suggesting is a limit in the new norm that we cannot calculate,but the limit in the final line of the proof($\gamma$) is a limit in the usual euclidean norm that we know how to deal with, only for that limit  I can conclude the answer is $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n=1/\sqrt t $ Makes sense? By the way I meant this limit up there before your las comment, I had a typo

Comment: I don't really see what you mean. The new norm is not hard to calculate/estimate than the usual sup norm. Just slightly different. The limit in the last two lines of $\gamma$ is not in any norm, it's a pointwise limit, as all one cares is equality of functions (no topological concerns).